# Get The parserRuleContexts which Cause the SYntax error of the source code

Tags: java, antlr4

I need to get the Context name that causes the syntax error in the source code using the antlr4. Is there a way to do that.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding the ParserRuleContext when there is a Syntax error in the source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57951251/adding-the-parserrulecontext-when-there-is-a-syntax-error-in-the-source-code)

Comment: @MikeLischke two different ones. adding to parseTree and getting the rule is two different types

Answer (score 0):

In your error listener (when the function `syntaxError` is called) you can use the passed in recognizer (which is actually your parser) to get the current parse rule context, by calling `Parser.getRuleContext()`.